# Installing gifski in Colab fails

Tags: r, installation, google-colaboratory, gif

I'm trying to install `gifski` on Google Colab:

```
install.packages("gifski")
library(gifski)
```

but the following error arises:

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Warning message in install.packages("gifski"):
“installation of package ‘gifski’ had non-zero exit status”
Error in library(gifski): there is no package called ‘gifski’
Traceback:

1. library(gifski)
```

So, is it possible to install and use `gifski` on Colab?

Thanks!

Comment: Using `install.packages("gifski", dependencies=TRUE)` produces the same error.

Comment: Is there no error message before that? Usually the first error message tells you what went wrong. This is just the generic "something went wrong" message at the end of the process. It's hard to say without the full output of `install.packages()`

Comment: @MrFlick that was the only error message the Colab R Kernle gave.

Answer (score 1):

*Documentation: https://gif.ski/*

**Packages**
You first need to install the required packages

```
!apt install ffmpeg
!apt install pngquant
```

**Rust**

You then need to install rust on Colab:

```
!apt install rustc
```

**Gifski**

Now we can install gifski, it requires some time (4 min)

```
!cargo install gifski
```

**Set env path**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/root/.cargo/bin')

%set_env PATH=/root/.cargo/bin
```

**check gifski version**

```
!gifski -V
```

Comment: your answer was truly correct for a Colab Python Kernel. However, I was looking for a solution for the Colab R Kernel. No problem: I' ve adapted the code you proposed to R language and it works fine.

Comment: I don't know why but the answer you've proposed and I've adapted to R language doesn't work anymore, arising also the error stated in the question.  The R code I've used is: `system("apt-get install -y libffmpeg-dev libpngquant-dev") / system("apt-get install rustc") / install.packages("gifski") / library(gifski)`.